# Deploing React site with ChackraUI on Vercel and modal window stopped showing

Tags: reactjs, vercel, modal-window, chakra-ui

I have a page with a modal window. In development mode, it opens. But when I upload my React App to vercel, then the screen just darkens there, and the modal window does not appear, but all the window controls work. Who faced the same problem?

```
const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>
            <Lorem count={2} />
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant="ghost">Secondary Action</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by upgrading the `"framer-motion": version` -> `"framer-motion": "^4.1.16"`.